# What does the function given to setTimeout get called with?

Tags: javascript

I have code like this:

```
setTimeout(foo, 600);
```

I always thought that `foo` didn't take any arguments, e.g.:

```
function foo() { /* bars */ }
```

However, doing the following:

```
function foo(a) { alert(a); /* bars */ }
```

Popped up an alert displaying -7. What does this number represent?

Comment: Great question!  I had never thought of trying this before.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is the time difference (in milliseconds) from when it was scheduled to run it and when it actually ran.

```
alert(setTimeout(function(a) { alert(a) }, 2000));
```

If you clear the first alert in time, you will see the next alert is somewhere -10 to 10.  If you wait a few seconds, you will see something that is around the time you waited minus 2000.

The same thing can be seen for setInterval.  Run the following in Firebug:

```
setInterval(function(a) { alert(a); }, 2000);
```

Try closing the alert quick, it will be around 0 again.  Leave it open - it will give you a large value.

**Note** This is on Firefox Mac, where keeping an alert open will halt processing of Javascript, so the timer does not execute until I close the alert.  The behavior of the tests above may be different in other browsers

Comment: yep.. it is documented in a very minor way here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout . looks like it's a firefox-only thing

Comment: Quite a clever feature, shame IE doesn't have it too.  Then again it's a shame IE doesn't have a lot of things :-)

Comment: @Andy E If you look at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=394769 it seems there is quite a controversy over its existence at all, since it reduces the usability of functions with optional arguments being called by setTimeout.

Comment: A very good point.  A check for `arguments.caller == null` would seem like the most appropriate workaround in that situation.  It does look like it might be removed soon to be HTML5 compliant, however.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can tell... the argument in the difference between when it was scheduled and when it actually ran in milliseconds. Interestingly enough, seems certain browsers like even fractions of whole seconds...

```
<script>
var a = setInterval(foo, 125);

console.log(a);

function foo(b) {
 console.log(b);
}
</script>
```

will output a bunch of zeros, same goes for 250, 500, 1000... while

```
<script>
var a = setInterval(foo, 127);

console.log(a);

function foo(b) {
 console.log(b);
}
</script>
```

will output

```
 -2
12
-6
8
-10
4
2
0
-2
-4
9
-8
5
3
1
```