# Javascript: What argument does the function specified in body's onload event get called with?

Tags: javascript, firefox, events, dom, browser

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293096/javascript-what-does-the-function-given-to-settimeout-get-called-with/2293182#2293182) question, my HTML looks like this:

```
<body id="body" onload="loader()">
</body>
```

I always assume, as [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload) says, that onload is given no arguments. However, I named the argument, and did some deep inspection, and found that I got an object looking like this:

```
{originalTarget : DOM, 
preventCapture : function, 
target : DOM, 
cancelable : Bool, 
currentTarget : DOM, 
timeStamp : Int, 
bubbles : Bool, 
type : String, 
eventPhase : Int, 
preventDefault : function, 
initEvent : function, 
stopPropagation : function, 
CAPTURING_PHASE : Int, 
AT_TARGET : Int, 
BUBBLING_PHASE : Int, 
explicitOriginalTarget : DOM, 
preventBubble : function,
isTrusted : Bool, 
MOUSEDOWN : Int, 
MOUSEUP : Int, 
MOUSEOVER : Int, 
//... (more constants)
}
```

Anyone have any idea what that thing is, or what its classname might be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That appears to be the standard JavaScript DOM [Event](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event) object.  It describes the nature of the event that your function is handling.

**UPDATE In response to comment discussion:**

Different browsers supply the Event object in different ways:

- IE never passes it as an argument to the function and instead uses the `window.event` property.
- Firefox will pass it as the first argument.
- Chrome seems to do both.

Comment: I believe any function called by any event handler (i.e. not just `body.onload`) gets passed this object as its first argument.

Comment: @Paul: I thought there were differences between browser implementations and the way events were attached (using the traditional or the advanced event registration models). But I could be completely wrong (and too tired to look for it at the moment).

Comment: @Marcel: Going to the spec in the first place is unfortunately a rarity today for young programmers. Nice work, Detective ;)

Comment: Nice update. I just found this comprehensive page: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html

Comment: @Marcel: sorry, you and Douglas are completely right. I’ve only really done event object stuff in jQuery, which always gives you an event object.

Comment: @Tim: The specs of W3C, that Douglas linked to: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event

Comment: @Marcel: Oh I see, I thought you were talking about how the event object is passed into event handlers defined by HTML attributes, which I thought had no formal specification.

Comment: @Tim: The definition for the `EventListener` interface does specify an `Event` parameter for the `handleEvent` method.  This would hardly be the first time browsers broke the spec though. ;)

Comment: @Douglas: There's a difference between how browsers handle events set via an HTML attribute and via an event handler property, and it was specifically the setting via an attribute that I thought had no formal spec. See this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196299/why-the-subtle-cross-browser-differences-in-event-object/2196356#2196356