# Check Value of a FORM POST on submit using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, post

I have 3 buttons `<input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="something">`. Then i check the event with `$(".form_name").submit(function(e) {` and i would like to check which of the 3 buttons have been clicked and to alert the user of the action and return false if the user wishes to not go through with the action.

How do i check which of these buttons have been clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event.target` might help.  Another workaround is to have the three buttons fire events, and make their event handler do the submission.  In that sense there is no guesswork.

—

Personally I would first make sure that the three buttons have identifiers, plausibly tucked within with `$(element).data` lines, or custom HTML attributes (oh, don’t use special classes!), and have the event handler check `$(event.target).data(key)` or `$(event.target).attr(key)` to find out more information related to the caller.  I would then map the form’s submit event also to this handler, so everything is processed from one place.

Comment: +1 I would also bind three separate events to those three buttons.

Comment: turns out you can return true/false on a click event to stop a form from being submitted. +1 + accepted

Answer (score 1):

The [Event interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event) gives information about the event. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293288/javascript-what-argument-does-the-function-specified-in-bodys-onload-event-get/2293303#2293303) to know where you can find this object.

The `target` or `scrElement` of the object is the attribute you're looking for. See [Quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html).

**EDIT:** you asked for a jQuery specific answer. You can just use [**event.target**](http://docs.jquery.com/Types/Event#event.target) (in your case `e.target`), jQuery fixes this when necessary.